# Form accept terms is not validated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I want to archive that the signup form give a validation error if the "accept terms" checkbox is not checked. for some reason the validation messages for all fields appear correctly but not for that checkbox.

*users/new.html.erb:*

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>

            <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

            <%= f.text_field :name, class: "login", placeholder: :name 

            ...more fields...

            <%= f.check_box :agreement, class: "field login-checkbox" %>
            <label class="choice" for="Field"><%= t("agree_terms")  %></label>

            <%= f.submit t("register"), class: "button btn btn-primary btn-large" %>

<% end %>
```

*models/user.rb:*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

      validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
      validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

      # this is the validation
      validates :agreement, acceptance: { accept: true }

...
end
```

Comment: adding `allow_nil: false` did the trick!

Comment: now the field gets always validated as "not checked" even if checked...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#acceptance

```
validates :agreement, acceptance: true
```

should do the trick for you.

Comment: actually I'm now facing the problem that the error message appears even if the check box is checked.